# Creating nested dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary, hyperlink, nodes

I am having a data for nodes in csv format. I want to create a dictionary for the analysis. The data I have looks like

```
Init node   Term node   Capacity 
   1    2   25900.20064
   1    3   23403.47319
   2    1   25900.20064
   2    6   4958.180928
   3    1   23403.47319
   3    4   17110.52372
   3    12  23403.47319
   4    3   17110.52372
   4    5   17782.7941
```

So one node is connected to other node having some capacity. So, I want a dictionary in python which creates a data like this

```
graph = {'1': {'2': 25900.20064, '3': 23403.47319},
         '2': {'1': 25900.20064, '6':4958.180928},
         '3': {'1': 23403.47319, '4'}}
```

I tried following code to do this..

```
import xlrd
file_location = "C:/Users/12/Desktop/SiouxFalls_net1.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
dict = {}
z = {}


for rows in range(sheet.nrows):
    a = sheet.cell_value(rows,0)
    dict[a] = {}
    for rows in range(sheet.nrows):
        b = sheet.cell_value(rows,1)
        c = sheet.cell_value(rows, 2)
        dict[a][b] = c
```

But I am having trouble in picking up the unique value from first column and assign other nodes data linked to it. Please help!

```
print(dict)
```

Comment: `dict` is a built in type, so that variable should be renamed. Also, could you also check the indentation of the second for loop? I suspect that the copy-paste may have messed up the indentation of the second loop.

Comment: Yes, the indentation is not correct here but I am not getting correct dictionary. I just wanna know if it is possible to create in the format want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this loop:

```
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
d = {}
for rows in range(sheet.nrows):
    a = sheet.cell_value(rows, 0)
    b = sheet.cell_value(rows, 1)
    c = sheet.cell_value(rows, 2)

    d.setdefault(a, {})[b] = c
    d.setdefault(b, {})[a] = c
```

Comment: Yeah this works. Thanks! a lot So, you are taking a values and trying to create an empty dict inside d and then again doing same with b. Am I right?

Comment: setdefault will create a dict with default value (empty dict in this case) if its not already created

Comment: Correct, setdefault() creates a new entry (empty dictionary in this case) only if there is no such entry associated with the given key.

Then it returns the entry (either the newly created empty or the existing one), so we add into the entry (which is nested dictionary) the new relation.